# Keyboard's globe button () was disappeared, iOS 15

Tags: ios, uikit, uikeyboard

when updated to iOS 15 , my app got this issue. Keyboard's globe button ( at left bottom corner) was disappeared, but we could click it.

Does anyone have an idea of what could be happening here?

[image]

Comment: Same problem . Did u figure out ?

Comment: Not yet, it is very strange.

Comment: Set image of 'UIKeyboardDockItemButton' to nil when debugging, the 'globe' will be back.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**tl;dr:** I found method **setFrame:** in a category of UIImageView like this.

```
-(void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame{
    xxxxxx;
    if (yyyyyy) {
        zzzzzz;
    }
    [super setFrame: frame];
}
```

Remove this category, globe button was back.